# how to insert ajax tool confirm button c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am new at AJAX When i enter the web page it gives an error which is
``(c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\RSS_proje\RSS_proje\WebApplication2-5.2\ShareRss.aspx 
        var lblMsg = $get('<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>');){"Control 'ScriptManager1' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."}

```
javascript side


HTML code[code:html]<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

```
  function onCancel() {
    var lblMsg = $get('<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>');
    lblMsg.innerHTML = "You clicked the <b>Cancel</b> button of AJAX confirm.";
}
```

```
  also, button side



   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Share RSS" BackColor="#FF6600" 
            BorderColor="#FF9933" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
            Width="78px" onclick="Button1_Click" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server"
TargetControlID="Button1"
ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to share this?"
OnClientCancel="CancelClick" />
 <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
```

C# SIDE

```
                 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "You clicked the <b>OK</b> button of AJAX confirm";
     }
```

Comment: the ajax is executed before the button click method

Comment: scriptmanager must inside into <form><asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></form> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ScriptManager tag is formatted exactly as you have it posted then make sure you're providing the appropriate closing tag for it. If you already are could you post a bit more of your markup so we can gat a better picture of how your Dom is structured